# How to set the input of a Keras layer with a Tensorflow tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672114/add-tensorflow-pre-processing-to-existing-keras-model-for-use-in-tensorflow-ser), I used Keras' `Layer.set_input()` to connect my Tensorflow pre-processing output tensor to my Keras model's input. However, [this method has been removed](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commit/92e8a20761bedbde8fd56a02a165884e8132f045) after Keras version `1.1.1`.

How can I achieve this in newer Keras versions?

**Example:**

```
# Tensorflow pre-processing
raw_input = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
### some TF operations on raw_input ###
tf_embedding_input = ...    # pre-processing output tensor

# Keras model
model = Sequential()
e = Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=maxlen)

### THIS DOESN'T WORK ANYMORE ###
e.set_input(tf_embedding_input)
################################

model.add(e)
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After you are done with pre-processing, You can add the tensor as input layer by calling `tensor` param of `Input`

So in your case:

```
tf_embedding_input = ...    # pre-processing output tensor

# Keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(tensor=tf_embedding_input)) 
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=maxlen))
```

Comment: On this line `model.add(Input(tensor=tf_embedding_input))`, the following **error is raised**: `TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("tf_embedding_input:0", shape=(?, 23), dtype=int64)`. I **solved this** by changing the line to `model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=embedding_input))`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though!

Comment: No problem, I usually use the functional `Model` and not `Sequential` where `Input` works, but glad that you fixed it at your end

Comment: Yes, I had previously used the functional `Model` and wrapped the pre-processing in a `Lambda` layer following an `Input` layer: `Lambda(preprocess_func, ...)`. Can I assume that, practically, this achieves the same thing?

Comment: It should .. infact I was about to suggest the same in my answer. But then I saw you are creating a placeholder for string `tf.placeholder(tf.string)`. And since I don't work on NLP, I was not certain if it plays will with keras