# How to set the input of a Keras layer of a functional model, with a Tensorflow tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have two packages I'd like to use, one is written in Keras1.2, and the other one in tensorflow. I'd like to use a part of the architecture that is built in tensorflow into a Keras model.

A partial solution is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441431/how-to-set-the-input-of-a-keras-layer-with-a-tensorflow-tensor), but it's for a sequential model. The suggestion regarding functional models - wrapping the pre-processing in a Lambda layer - didn't work.

The following code worked:

```
inp = Input(shape=input_shape)
def ID(x):
    return x
lam = Lambda(ID)  
flatten = Flatten(name='flatten')
output = flatten(lam(inp))
Model(input=[inp], output=output)
```

But, when replacing `flatten(lam(inp))` with a pre-processed output tensor `flatten(lam(TF_processed_layer))`, I got: "Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found: Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)"

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping your input tensor into the Keras Input layer and carry on building your model from there. Like so:

```
inp = Input(tensor=tftensor,shape=input_shape)
def ID(x):
    return x
lam = Lambda(ID)  
flatten = Flatten(name='flatten')
output = flatten(lam(inp))
Model(input=inp, output=output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining your lamba correctly for Keras. 
Try something like this

```
def your_lambda_layer(x):
    x -= K.mean(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    x = K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)
    return x

....
model.add(Lambda(your_lambda_layer))
```

of seeing you are using the Functional API like this

```
def your_lambda_layer(x):
    x -= K.mean(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    x = K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)
    return x

....
x = SomeLayerBeforeLambda(options...)(x)
x = (Lambda(your_lambda_layer))(x)
```

But even so, the lambda layer may not be able to be flattened so printout the shape of the lambda and take a look at it and see what it is.