# Use keras layer in tensorflow code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Lets say I have a simple neural network with an input layer and a single convolution layer programmed in tensorflow:

```
  # Input Layer
  input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])

  # Convolutional Layer #1
  conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

I leave out any further parts of the network definitions for the `features`.

If I wanted to add an LSTM Layer after this convolution layer, I would have to make the convolution layer [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/) (in the language of keras) and then put the output of the TimeDistributed layer into the LSTM.

Tensorflow offers access to the keras layers in [tf.keras.layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed). Can I use the keras layers directly in the tensorflow code? If so, how? Could I also use the [tf.keras.layers.lstm](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) for the implementation of the LSTM Layer?

So in general: Is a mixture of pure tensorflow code and keras code possible and can I use the tf.keras.layers?

Comment: I think this question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441431/how-to-set-the-input-of-a-keras-layer-with-a-tensorflow-tensor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the input of a Keras layer with a Tensorflow tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441431/how-to-set-the-input-of-a-keras-layer-with-a-tensorflow-tensor)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Import both TensorFlow and Keras and link your Keras session to the TF one:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import backend as K

tf_sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(tf_sess)
```

Now, in your model definition, you can mix TF and Keras layers like so:

```
# Input Layer
input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])

# Convolutional Layer #1
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=32,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)

# Flatten conv output
flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(conv1)

# Fully-connected Keras layer
layer2_dense = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat)

# Fully-connected TF layer (output)
output_preds = tf.layers.dense(layer2_dense, units=10)
```

This answer is adopted from [a Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) post by Francois Chollet.

Comment: So then `preds` would be a keras layer, right? Is there a way to put this back into a tensorflow layer/operation?

Comment: @Merlin1896 You can mix and match any layers you want. I have updated the answer so that the final layer is a standard tensorflow layer

Comment: @Merlin1896 if this answered your question you can mark it as answered so that others may find it as well

Comment: Could you provide a complete minimal example for future reference? The current code won't run :)

Comment: @Merlin1896 I changed the example to fit in with your convolutional example. It should run now! In the example I used a Keras dense layer since I'm not sure how exactly you are going to implement the LSTM