# Using tf.keras within Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

What is the correct way of using the `tf.keras` API. Can `tf.layers.*` be directly replaced with `tf.keras.layers`(Similarly activations or loss functions)? Is it necessary to import `tf.keras.backend` and do `set_learning_phase`? This doesnt seem to be explained on the [official TF docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras) but is mentioned in this [relatively old blog post](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I refer you to: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167630/use-keras-layer-in-tensorflow-code?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). It even contains link to a blog that explains the compatibility.

Comment: I've linked to the blog in my question as well - The point is that that post is old and related to using `keras` directly and not `tf.keras`. My question can be thought of as whether all those instructions also apply to `tf.keras` directly and are there any related updates/restrictions?