# Using a Tensorflow feature_column in a Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

How can a Tensorflow `feature_column` be used in conjunction with a Keras model?

E.g. for a Tensorflow estimator, we can use an embedding column from Tensorflow Hub:

```python
embedded_text_feature_column = hub.text_embedding_column(
    key="sentence", 
    module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1")

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
hidden_units=[100],
feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column],
n_classes=2,
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001))
```

However, I would like to use the TF Hub `text_embedding_column` as input to a Keras model. E.g.

```python
net = tf.keras.layers.Input(...) # use embedding column here
net = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
net = Dense(100, activation='relu')(net)
net = Dense(2)(net)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be that you don't use feature columns. `Keras` comes with its own set of preprocessing functions for images and text, so you can use those.

So basically the `tf.feature_columns` are reserved for the high level API. Then the `tf.keras.preprocessing()` functions are used with `tf.keras` models.

Here is a link to the section on preprocessing data in the `keras` documentation. 
https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/

Here is another Stackoverflow post that has an example of this approach.

[Add Tensorflow pre-processing to existing Keras model (for use in Tensorflow Serving)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672114/add-tensorflow-pre-processing-to-existing-keras-model-for-use-in-tensorflow-ser)

Answer (score 1):

The keras functional api is a viable way to do this, but if you want to use `feature_columns` this tutorial shows you how:

https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/feature_columns

Basically it's this `DenseFeatures` layer that does the job:

```
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```